# Почему не работает звук игры на Android устройстве сделанной на unity WebGl?

Tags: unity3d, аудио, отладка, webgl

Не работает звук игры сделанной на unity WebGl, запущенной через браузер на Android устройстве, но на других устройствах звук есть.

Comment: Подключите андроид через [Android Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) и посмотрите какие ошибки выдает браузер.
Unity использует WebAudio API для воспроизведения звуков в WebGL сборках. Можете поискать [решение или описание проблемы](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues) у них.